# pthread_join is being a bottleneck

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, pthreads

I have an application where `pthread_join` is being the bottleneck. I need help to resolve this problem.

```
void *calc_corr(void *t) {
         begin = clock();
         // do work
         end = clock();
         duration = (double) (1000*((double)end - (double)begin)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
         cout << "Time is "<<duration<<"\t"<<h<<endl;
         pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main() {
         start_t = clock();

         for (ii=0; ii<16; ii++) 
            pthread_create(&threads.p[ii], NULL, &calc_corr, (void *)ii);

         for (i=0; i<16; i++) 
            pthread_join(threads.p[15-i], NULL);

         stop_t = clock();

         duration2 = (double) (1000*((double)stop_t - (double)start_t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
         cout << "\n Time is "<<duration2<<"\t"<<endl;

         return 0;
}
```

The time printed in the thread function is in the range of **40ms - 60ms** where as the time printed in the main function is in the **650ms - 670ms**. The irony is, my serial code runs in **650ms - 670ms** time. what can I do to reduce the time taken by `pthread_join`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 16 * 40ms = 640ms. I doubt this is a coincidence. How many cores do you have?

Comment: print out all the begin and end's clocked in calc_corr, and see what the difference between the very first time clocked on begin and the very last clocked on end. My bet is that you will find that most of the time is spent waiting on at least one or more threads.

Comment: I have 8 cores and I am binding 2 threads per core using pthread_setaffinity_np.

Comment: How many cores do you have? ... and how many of them can be used? Did you verify that the different threads aren't effectively running serialized? That is, you might want to print the start/end times of the different threads, too. It may also be worth collecting the threads in the same order they are started given that the thread started first had more chance of doing work than the others.

Comment: Your main time calculation is also paying overhead for 16 threads to do their cout printing.  You should have no printing done within your timestamps

Comment: There is also the potential that there is a dependency on caches if the threads do work on data which is close to each other.

Comment: I have run this without measuring time within the threads. So, cout, though generally an issue, doesn't seem to be one this time around.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On Linux, `clock()` measures the combined CPU time. **It does not measure the wall time.**

This is explains why you get `~640 ms = 16 * 40ms`. (as pointed out in the comments)

To measure wall time, you should be using something like:

- [`gettimeofday()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/gettimeofday.html)
- [`clock_gettime()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime)

Comment: Or `clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, ...)` for nanosecond resolution.

Comment: Thanks, added that to answer.

Answer (score 1):

By creating some threads you are adding an overhead to your system: Creation time, scheduling time. Creating a thread require allocating the stack, etc; scheduling means more context switching. Also, `pthread_join  suspends execution of the calling thread until the target thread terminates`. Which means you want for thread 1 to finish, when he does you are rescheduled as quick as possible but not instantly, then you wait for thread 2,  etc...

Now your computer has few cores, like one or 2, and you are creating 16 threads. At best 2 threads of your program will run at the same time and just by adding their clock measurements you have something around `400 ms`.

Again It depends on lot of things, so I quickly flown over what is happening.